# Run a time-constrained shell command

Tags: linux, shell

I'm looking for the simplest way to run a command in a shell and kill it if it doesn't end in less than a second of CPU time. Something like:

```
$ deadline -- slow-foo
Started fooing...
[deadline] 1 sec deadline hit, killing and returning -1!

$ deadline -- quick-foo
Started fooing...
Finished fooing!
```

A linux-based solution is more than enough, but more portable ones are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Coreutils has a [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) utility that does just that, should be available on most Linux distributions:

> `timeout` - run a command with a time limit

Has options for what signal to use and a few other things.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of [`timeout(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)  given in [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351314/841108), and if you want to limit [*CPU* time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) (not *idle* time or *real* time), you could use the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_CPU` (if the CPU time limit is exceeded, your process gets first a `SIG_XCPU` signal -which it could catch and handle-, and later a `SIG_KILL` -uncatchable- signal). This syscall is available in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) with the `ulimit` builtin.

So to limit CPU time to 90 seconds (i.e. 1 minute and 30 seconds) type

```
 ulimit -t 90
```

in your terminal (assuming your shell is `bash`; with [zsh](http://zsh.org/) use `limit cputime 90`, etc...) - then all further commands are constrained by that limit

Read also the instructive [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man pages, and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty and doesn't require any software packages to be installed, so is portable:

```
TIMEOUT=1
YOURPROGRAM & PID=$! ; (sleep $TIMEOUT && kill $PID 2> /dev/null & ) ; wait $PID
```